# Probability Problem exam

Tags: probability, statistics

An exam consists of two questions. A student passes the exam if she gives the right answer to the second question, regardless of her answer to the first one. The first question is a True/False one. The students that give the right answer to this first question are posed another True/False question. Meanwhile, the students that fail to answer correctly to the first question are posed a multiple-choice question with 8 possible answers. If a student answers both questions at random,

a) what is the probability that she passes the exam?

b) what is the probability that she gives the right answer to the first question, but fails at the second?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Seems like you can just write out all the cases, no?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to start:

$A$: Answer the first question right

$B$: Answer the second question with two options right

$C$: Answer the second question with eight options right.

$P(\texttt{Answer the second question right})$

$=P((A\cap B)\cup (A^c \cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)+ P(A^C)\cdot P(C|A^C)$